# split json array in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I am new in angular.when I try to fetch value of textbox which is in a loop getting json array in this format - in the formsubmit method if I do console.log(myForm.value) then I get this big list:

```
[
    {
       "product-0":"Voltas",
       "avi-0":"5",
       "def-0":"0",
       "quantity-0":3,
       "product-1":"Voltas1",
       "avi-1":"5",
       "def-1":"1",
       "quantity-1":3,
       "product-2":"Voltas2",
       "avi-2":"5",
       "def-2":"7",
       "quantity-2":1,
       "product-3":"Voltas0",
       "avi-3":"5",
       "def-3":"6",
       "quantity-3":1
   } 
]
```

can anyone help me to get json in this format

```
[
   {
      "product-0":"Voltas",
      "avi-0":"5",
      "def-0":"0",
      "quantity-0":3
   },
   {
      "product-1":"Voltas",
      "avi-0":"5",
      "def-0":"0",
      "quantity-0":3
   }
]
```

in angular 2.thanks in advance.
this is my html code

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">  
  <ion-item *ngFor="let productlist of productlists;let i = index">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-15><input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" [(ngModel)]="productlist.product" name="product-{{i}}" /> {{productlist.product}}</ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25><input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" [(ngModel)]="productlist.avi" name="avi-{{i}}"/>{{productlist.avi}}</ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25><input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" [(ngModel)]="productlist.def" name="def-{{i}}"/>{{productlist.def}}</ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25 class="add">
      <button clear (click)="increment(productlist)"><ion-icon name="add-circle" ></ion-icon></button>            
          <ion-item><ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="productlist.quantity"  name="quantity-{{i}}" class="quantity"></ion-input></ion-item>                
      <button clear (click)="decrement(productlist)"><ion-icon name="remove-circle" ></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-col>          
    </ion-row>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="formSubmit(myForm.value)">submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Show us some code.. How you are fetching the value?

Comment: I edited my code

Comment: I would like to see this part _fetch value of textbox which is in a loop getting json array_

Comment: In order to fix the JSON problem, you need to show us the code that is generating the JSON - are you saying that when the user clicks the submit button that console.log(myForm.value) outputs the json as one big list? We don't know what is producing the JSON you are referring to.

Comment: Also note you should not have multiple HTML elements with the same id. You have id="hiddenValue" - please make them different, like you have for the name attribute, or remove them if you don't need ids

Comment: yes console.log(myForm.value) this will generate big json

Comment: I think you need to build this with nested forms and I would advise using reactive forms to do it. I advise reading this article which will help: https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4

Comment: Use nested form groups https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#nested-formgroups

Comment: You can make use of FormArray for getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you have a **single form** and a **single form can only return a single object.**

If you want to split that into multiple objects then you need to write code in your submit method to iterate through 'the big list' and create the structure you want:

[ {} ]  => [ {}, {}. {} ]

You would have to search for `object.keys.substr(0,6)` matching 'product'. **This is not a good idea even though it could work.**

What I suggest instead is that you create nested forms - one form for each item in the list. I suggest you use reactive forms for this, as it is much easier.

This is because you need to create a component that represents a single product in your array:

[ {}, {}, {} ] = 
[{product-item}, {product-item}, {product-item}]

ie:
ProductList-Component has a form with ngFor and inside the ngFor you load multiple children, like this:

```
  <product-item *ngFor="let product of productlists"
    [product]="product">
  </product-item>
```

Notice that this product-item component will need an @Input, which is a formGroup, eg:

```
  @Input()
  public product: FormGroup;
```

See [this article](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4) to learn how you can build this.

In particular see the section that starts with "First idea is obviously to extract a component that represents a single item in the form array"